# How to only disable 'no-throw-literal' webpack warnings?

Tags: webpack

I'm using `webpack@3.8.1`

I'll be creating actual error objects in the future. For the moment, I'd like to disable all 'no-throw-literal' warnings globally. How can I do this (without typing `// eslint-disable-next-line` before each one)?

PS: I have bootstrapped my react app with `create-react-app`

Answer (score 4):

This is an `ESLint` error, not a `webpack` error.
ESLint is a widely used tool for linting JS and TS projects, and it is configurable in many ways. The default configuration in CRA projects resides in the `package.json` file, under `eslintConfig`.
In order to disable a rule altogether, simply update your `eslintConfig` to look like so:

```
{
  "eslintConfig": {
    /* ESLint configuration, you can leave the default values */
    "rules": {
      "no-throw-literal": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your linter. For example for `@typescript-eslint` you can add this rule:

`.eslintrc.js`

```sh
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal": 0,
  }
```